# How can I pass a SSL certificate to a SOAP server using SOAPpy / Python

Tags: python, ssl, x509, soappy

I am building a script to access a HTTPS/TLS TCP site that requires a X.509 certifcate that I have as a .pfx file.

I am using SOAPpy 0.12.5 and Python 2.7 and have started off with code as below,

```
import SOAPpy
url = "192.168.0.1:5001"
server = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy(url)

# I think I need to pass the cert to server here...

server.callSoapRPC(xxxx)
```

If I try running this it fails with the following message

```
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Any sugestions how to tie the .pfx certificate to the SOAPproxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it this way:

```
import SOAPpy
SOAPpy.Config.SSL.cert_file = 'cert_file'
SOAPpy.Config.SSL.key_file = 'key_file'

server = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy(url, config=config)
```

Comment: How did you create the cert file and key file?  The documentation for the SOAP service I'm trying to connect to says "get a copy of the EAI system’s certificate.
The certificate must be a signed X.509 certificate encoded using Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM)
Base64-encoding."

Comment: Weird, weird, why doesn't my SOAPpy has the `SOAPpy.Config.SSL` object?

Comment: Giovanni P, try to
`pip install -U soappy`